# Event Listener In Class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class

I added an Event Listener in class, for an object, that is not on frame 1, and it's not working. Is there any way I can make it work?

My code is:

```
package Home
{

    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;


    public class Home extends SimpleButton
    {
        public var Home_mc:SimpleButton;

        public function Home()
        {

            Home_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, home_1);
        }

        function home_1(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            //gotoAndStop('Home',"Home-sc");
            trace("CLICKED");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks crazy, is your code in the timeline or a separate class file? `package Home` are you sure that is the right package too (usually not a good idea to have the package the same name as the class, can get confusing). Is `Home_mc` a library asset with an export class name `Home` ?

Comment: As @R. Vander Linden has stated you haven't made an instance of `Home_mc` that is: `Home_mc = new SimpleButton();` is that what you were planning to do?

Comment: My code is in separate class file. I'm new to AS3 sorry for troubling.
I want to know if 'var Home_mc:Simplebutton = new SimpleButton();'
or Entering an instance name by clicking on the object.Are both of them the same thing?

Comment: What I did now  is added an Instance name"Home_mc" to Home button.Linked the class file to it. It is working fine now. But when I use gotoAndStop() it gives me an Error,"Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndStop()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public var Home_mc:SimpleButton;
```

You are declaring a variable here, but I'm not really sure why. It is declared but I don't see you making an instance from it and placing it on screen.

I'm guessing you are making an instance from home an showing that on the screen.
Then you should just add the event to your class and not the home_mc variable.

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, home_1);
```

Edit for completeness:

you could link the as3 class to a button symbol

```
package  
{
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Home extends SimpleButton
    {
        public function Home()
        {
            // Add the event to instances of this class
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, home_1);
        }

        function home_1(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            //gotoAndStop('Home',"Home-sc");
            trace("CLICKED");
        }
    }

}
```

Then you can make an instance of the class from somewhere else and use addchild on some displayobject.

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class start extends MovieClip 
    {
        public function start() 
        {
            var home:Home = new Home();
            this.addChild(home);
        }
    }
}
```

> My code is in separate class file. I'm new to AS3 sorry for troubling. I want to know if >'var Home_mc:Simplebutton = new SimpleButton();' or Entering an instance name by clicking >on the object.Are both of them the same thing?

Yes, this is basicly the same.

> What I did now is added an Instance name"Home_mc" to Home button.Linked the class file to >it. It is working fine now. But when I use gotoAndStop() it gives me an Error,"Call to a >possibly undefined method gotoAndStop()"

From what you seem to try to achieve, I wouldn't use a simplebutton class but extend a movieclipclass. There are some differences between the two. Maybe this tutorial can guide you a little bit: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0VhiqQVMpY

Comment: "this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, home_1);"
or 
"addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, home_1);" they are the same, isn't?
I linked to to Home button, I used trace function it is working fine.
but when I Use gotoAndStop, It gives me an error "Call to a possibly undefined method".

Comment: first question: That should work to. Think it's an old habbit of me to write "this." infront of methods that are from a baseclass.

Comment: 2nd question: gotoAndStop() is a movieclip method. In your example you are extending from simplebutton class. If you want to work with different frames and don't need the properties that are specific for the SimpleButton class, you can inherrit from Movieclip instead. If you linked it to a button symbol you need to change that symbol into a movieclip.